# Можно ли перегрузить опреатор [] как не член класса?

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

В целом вопрос в заголовке, не знаю что ещё добавить, кроме примера

Перегрузка как член класса:

```
class A
{
public:
    int* some_arr;

    int operator [](uint_t i)
    {
        return this->some_arr[i];
    }
}
```

Перегрузка, как я себе представляю, как не член класса:

```
class A
{
   // ...
public:
   int* some_arr;
   // ...
}

int operator [](const A& a, uint_t i) // либо поменять аргументы местами, поэтому-то и не уверен
{
    return a.some_arr[i];
}
```

И если перегружать как не член класса, то, получается, нужно передавать экземпляр, но сначала нужно передавать экземпляр, а потом индекс, или наоборот? Или вообще нельзя?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет:

> **16.5.5 Subscripting [over.sub]**
>
> 1 `operator[]` shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter.